# T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING whenever I try add a linebreak

Tags: php, mysql

```
 <?PHP
        $query  = "SELECT * FROM `projects` ";
        $query  .= "WHERE `v_active` = '1' ";
        $query  .= "ORDER BY `title` ASC "; 
        $result = mysql_query($query); 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            // GET DATA
            echo $row["title"]." "."<br />";
            echo ($row["v_address"])? " ".$row["v_address"] : "";
            echo ($row["v_email"])? "<a href='mailto:".$row["v_email"]."'>".$row["v_email"]."</a> <br />" : " ";
            echo ($row["v_website"])? "<a href='".$row["v_website"]."'>".$row["v_website"]."</a> <br />" : " ";
            echo ($row["v_comment"])? " ".$row["v_comment"] : "";


                    ?>
```

Hi! Sorry for the dumb question, but I'm trying to add another linebreak after the v_address field (like the other rows) but it seems like I can't wrap my head around the quotes or something because whenever I try add one I get a T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING error. Help for a newbie? Thanks!

Comment: Use an IDE such as NetBeans or PHP Storm - it will highlight where your syntax errors without needing to run any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how exactly you were doing it, but this should work

```
<?php

$query  = "SELECT * FROM `projects` ";
$query  .= "WHERE `v_active` = '1' ";
$query  .= "ORDER BY `title` ASC ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
// GET DATA
echo $row["title"]." "."<br />";
echo ($row["v_address"])? " ".$row["v_address"] . "<br/>" : "";
echo ($row["v_email"])? "<a href='mailto:".$row["v_email"]."'>".$row["v_email"]."</a> <br />" : " ";
echo ($row["v_website"])? "<a href='".$row["v_website"]."'>".$row["v_website"]."</a> <br />" : " ";
echo ($row["v_comment"])? " ".$row["v_comment"] : "";

?>
```

Comment: That won't work, your `while` brace is unclosed (though I acknowledge the same error occurs in the question). Also, whilst indentation is not mandatory, it is a very good idea!

Answer (score 1):

It should just be this -

```
echo ($row["v_address"])? " ".$row["v_address"] . "<br />" : "";
```